# angular 2 best way to constantly update dom position

Tags: angular, dom

I'm building a game in Angular (v4) and am fully aware that direct dom manipulation is rarely (if ever) the correct route for angular. However, for what I'm building, I'm not sure I see another viable avenue.

What I'm needing is a component that handles it's dom by updating rotational positions of several elements simultaneously (think of a solar system model). There are two main routes I see, the first is direct dom manipulation that updates on component input change. The second is a component where it has inline style tags e.g. `[style.whatever]="thing.whatever"`.

My second route seems kind of like it's still direct dom manipulation, just not in the javascript.

I like doing things the 'right' way whenever possible, so any input would be helpful.

I do not use/plan/want to use JQuery at all in this project.

**Update**

Just realized I'm an idiot, and I wouldn't need programmatic DOM updates, I just need to set the initial css properties for where I need it to start, and the animation speed. Since it's a constant thing, with a predictable animation, I can just let css do all the work. I would still like to know if it would be most proper to set those css properties in code, or as attributes of the component.

Answer (score 0):

Here what it comes to my mind quickly of what you can do (not comprehensive of course)

use bindings, like :

```
 @HostBinding('style.whatever')
   whatever: thing


  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  setHeight() {
    this.height = 200px;
  }
```

template variables

```
@ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;
<input #input ...>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I'm not really looking for how to do it, more if there were a method that was less dom manipulatey (<-- scientific term). Also, it wouldn't be on window resize or some external event, it would be every second or so.